# Import eclipse project (orphaned toolchain)

Tags: c++, eclipse, import

I have got a little problem. I imported a project (including its settings) in Eclipse (C/C++), but when I browse through those settings I constantly find Eclipse pointing out the following:

> Orphaned toolchain
>   org.eclipse.cdt.cross.arm.gnu.sourcery.windows.elf.toolchain.debug.154435017
>   (ARM Windows GCC (Sourcery G++ Lite))

I have no clue what this means. Can someone enlighten me please, and if possible point out a solution because I can't build my project and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an error caused because you've copied the `.settings` folder of the project but not the `.metadata` folder of the workspace. That I think is you were using some kind of eclipse extension or plugin in the origin workspace but you don't have it in the destination workspace.

Comment: No, that can not be it, i have a map called .metadata in my workspace folder (not in the project folder tho). So thats not it. But can you explain what it means, an orphaned toolchain?

Comment: I don't know what means this error in particular, I've told you that because the `.metadata/.plugins/` subfolders have names like `org.eclipse.foo.bar.` and maybe it lacks one in your destination workspace.

Comment: Aha that seems plausible. I have checked the destination folder and this indeed lacks the folder org.eclipse.cdt.cross.arm.... But then again the original folder does not have this either.. still i have no clue how to fix this. :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a missing app.  Go to **Help->Install New Software-> "select appropiate app"** in eclipse.